# Why Spark is using both NettyBlockTransferService and my BlockStoreClient?

Tags: apache-spark, shuffle

When running Spark App I've noticed that fetchBlocks function of both `NettyBlockTransferService` and my custom ShuffleClient (implementing `BlockStoreClient`) are being called.

I know what my ShuffleClient does (fetching remote data blocks), but I didn't understand what `NettyBlockTransferService` do, according to the docs it also responsible for fetching data blocks so why we need both?

I've tried to print the blocks list passed to `NettyBlockTransferService` and my ShuffleClient.
In my ShuffleClient I see a list of blocks as expected, i.e. tuple of (shuffle_id, map_id, reduce_id), but in `NettyBlockTransferService` the list looks like this:

```
fetchBlocks: broadcast_0_piece0
fetchBlocks: broadcast_1_piece0
fetchBlocks: rdd_1_2342
fetchBlocks: broadcast_2_piece0
```

...

So I'm not sure I understand what `NettyBlockTransferService` does exactly.

Edit: I'm might found an answer after discuss it with a colleague.
Spark sometimes need to broadcast data to all the executors, for example if you perform join of a small table with a very the Driver can just send the small table to all the executors so they can perform the join. For this it uses broadcast and it looks like it uses the NettyBlockTransferService to perform this broadcast.

Need confirmation for this explanation.